# Add a row of strings, like a second column name, to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add string data to the first row of a dataframe (i.loc[0,:])

So that when printed the dataframe looks something like so:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
A    B    C
4    2    4
1    6    2 
5    8    6
```

I would then like to total the column totals from the start of the numerical data (as the last row does in the dataframe above).

The motivation for this is to create a function which uses this string data in the second row (iloc[1,:]).

I have a few ideas, but the task seems daunting and would greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your data? This seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a multiple part question.

Assuming that the name of each column is Col1, Col2, Col3, and you want to add a row in which the value in the cell is a string I would try the following:

```
df.loc['index you want to insert your row into'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I am not sure if what you actually want is a header row (which would make more sense)

Regarding the sum total row I would try the following:

```
df.loc['Totals'] = df.sum()
```